# Does SetVaryByCustom work in User Controls?

Tags: asp.net

It seems to me that

```
Response.Cache.SetVaryByCustom("mykey");
```

is not working from within ASCX User Controls. It works from the Page. The ASCX works only when VaryByCustom is specified in the outputcache directive.

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider expressing it as a directive at the top of the ascx:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="1800" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="mykey" %>
```

Response is a property of Page, not of the control, so it's possible that it has no effect at the control level.